# Value of sum is not changing when buttons are clicked android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the value of sum based on the buttons that are clicked on my app but the value of sum is not changing.

How do I get the value of sum to change based on the user's choice of button clicking? Thank you.

Here is my code attached below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.example.admin.project3;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Project3 extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView textView;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_project3);

    SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.mySeekbar);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.mySeekBarNumber);
    TextView myPrice = findViewById(R.id.myPrice);
    RadioButton thickButton = findViewById(R.id.Thick);
    RadioButton soggyButton = findViewById(R.id.Soggy);
    RadioButton deliveryButton = findViewById(R.id.Deliver);
    CheckBox anch = findViewById(R.id.Anchovies);
    CheckBox pine = findViewById(R.id.Pineapple);
    CheckBox garlic = findViewById(R.id.Garlic);
    CheckBox okra = findViewById(R.id.Okra);

    double myInches = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString());
    double sum = 0;

    if(thickButton.isActivated()) sum += 2.50;
    if(soggyButton.isActivated()) sum += 5.00;
    if(deliveryButton.isActivated()) sum += 3.00;
    if(anch.isChecked()) sum += .05*myInches;
    if(pine.isChecked()) sum += .05*myInches;
    if(garlic.isChecked()) sum += .05*myInches;
    if(okra.isChecked()) sum += .05*myInches;

    sum += myInches*.05;
    String Price = Double.toString(sum);
    myPrice.setText(Price);



    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            textView.setText(progress + " in");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if buttons are "activated" and if your CheckBoxes &  RadioButtons are checked in onCreate(),
which means this test will **only** occur once the activity has started.

Instead, use `setOnClickListener()` on your Buttons, and `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`
for the RadioButtons & CheckBoxes, and then, whenever a change occurs - change the sum & set the text.

p.s
Variables shouldn't be named with capital letters in the beginning,
so change `String Price` to `String price`.

Comment: So is it supposed to be something like: thickButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                
            }
        });

Comment: For the Buttons, it's `setOnClickListener`, read more here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

Comment: Thanks I got it working! Realized I could've added everything I wanted to my seekbar progress change listener.